# Regaining access to a smart contract

Tags: ethereumj

So I have a tricky situation.

Sometime back we deployed a smart contract, let's call that as contractA owned by userA.

Then we needed to make some edits so we deployed another smart contract contractB and the idea was that ContractB should own ContractA and move some assets.

Now the tricky part:

Due to wrong deployment of contractB it has the userA address in constructor instead of contractA address while the owner of contractA has been changed to contractB

To sum it up:

ContractA is owned by ContractB

ContractB is owned by UserA

ContractB thinks UserA address is ContractA address and hence cannot take actions on ContractA

Is there any way we can solve this, and give userA access to contractA?

TIA

Comment: Did you use Ownable.sol contract by @Open.Zeppelin in your contract ownership implementation?

Comment: @Sky Yes we did use ownable.sol

Comment: Alright, than that is a saving grace, but I would have to se contracts or have a call to see if we might be able to solve that. It's hard to give advice on smartContracts when there is no code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to solve this unless `ContractB` has a function to transfer ownership of `ContractA`. You can change the ownership of `ContractB` but, without that function, `ContractB` can't change the ownership of `ContractA`

Comment: That wouldnt change anything, contractB has the wrong address for contractA

Comment: @Foxxxey I think you misread it
> ContractB thinks UserA address is ContractA address
> ContractA is owned by ContractB

Comment: That's what i'm saying. How could contractB call transferOwnership() on contract A if thinks UserA address is ContractA?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, there's nothing you can really do unless `contractB` has a function to change its `contractA` address (which it should have imo, but well, design descisions).